# Cannot connect to Canon LBP 2900B via ZTE router print server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, printer

I am trying to connect to my Canon LBP2900B USB printer to my ZTE F670L Wifi Router and access in my windows machine wirelessly. I have verified that USB printing is enabled on my wifi router. I can even see the printer connected to USB on the router control panel. But when I try to access the printer from any of my devices - windows , the printer cannot be reached. I try to connect to the printer via my router IP address - 192.168.1.1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th Canon LBP2900B is a CAPT printer. That is Canon's way of saying it does not support a printer language (PDL) but instead relies on the host PC's graphics engine to convert the page into dots on the paper.

These type of printers are hard to network. The best way is to share them from a PC - which then has to be on whenever anyone wants to print.

The other way is to use a **compatible** printserver. Most printserver have a list of supported printers. If your printer is not in the list you must assume it **will not work**.

I have not been able to find such a list for your router. Hence my recommendation is to either get a printer that supports a PDL (PCL5/6 or PostScript), or share the printer from a PC.

Note: some HP printers support a thing called PCL3. That is **not** a PDL.